# Local property of a flat family of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, deformation-theory

Let $\pi: X \to S$ be a flat, smooth family of genus $0$ curves, for example. Now take a point $x \in S$, then $x \in \pi{-1}(p)$ from some $p \in S$, i.e $x \in \mathbb{P}^1$.

I am trying to relate such families to first order infinitesimal deformations.

In particular, does there exist an open subset $ x\in U \subset X$ such that $U$ is a first order infinitesimal deformation of $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: In your first paragraph, $x \in S$ and (presumably) $x \in \pi^{-1}(p)$, which doesn't make sense.